# Check if a date in a column is within sets of date ranges

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have an appointments calendar where appointment dates go in column A. I'd like to flag where appointments may be on a school holiday.

Where column A contains dates and blanks. "SH" is what I want to appear in the array column (AM) where rows match a date in column A.

So if A200 is 7 Oct 2023, "SH" appears in AM200

```
School Holidays WA
Holiday         Start           Finish
Term 1 (Autumn) 29 Mar 2024 14 Apr 2024
Term 2 (Winter) 29 Jun 2024 14 Jul 2024
Term 3 (Spring) 23 Sep 2023 8 Oct 2023
Term 4 (Summer) 15 Dec 2023 30 Jan 2024

Named ranges...
Term1S is 29 Mar 2024 (Data!Z4)
Term1F is 14 Apr 2024 (Data!AA4)
Term2S is 29 Jun 2024 (Data!Z5)
Term2F is 14 Jul 2024 (Data!AA5)
Term3S is 23 Sep 2023 (Data!Z6)
Term3F is 8 Oct 2023  (Data!AA6)
Term4S is 15 Dec 2023 (Data!Z7)
Term4F is 30 Jan 2024 (Data!AA7)
```

And if you are a rocket scientist, to directly reference [this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=school+holidays+wa+2022&oq=school+ho&aqs=chrome.2.0i131i433i512j0i433i512j0i512j69i57j0i433i457i512j0i402j0i131i433i512j0i512j0i131i433i512j0i271l3.6516j0j4&client=ms-android-huawei-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) so that the lookup data doesn't need updating each year or so.

This works for one date range (term 1), but how do I include multiple ranges

```
={"S Hols";arrayformula(
  IF(IF(chkSH_Include=TRUE,(A3:A2049>=Term1S)*(A3:A2049<=Term1F),""),"SH","")
)}
```

chkSH_Include is a checkbox to turn onnclusions on or off

I'd like to clean it up, and add Terms 2-4?

```
Term2S is 29 Jun 2024
Term2F is 14 Jul 2024
Term3S is 23 Sep 2023
Term3F is 8 Oct 2023
Term4S is 15 Dec 2023
Term4F is 30 Jan 2024
```

I tried this but got:

> Array arguments to GTE are of different size.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(($A3:$A2049>=Data!Z4:Z7)*($A3:$A2049<=Data!AA4:AA7), "SH", "" ))
```